# Dynamic temporary index creation

Tags: performance, index

In my undergrad databases course, my professor mentioned that some DBMS software is so advanced that it can detect when a long-running query would benefit from an index. The DBMS can then create that index for the duration of the query to increase performance.

However, I don't think that's possible, and some initial Googling seems to agree with me. Does anyone know of a DBMS that actually implements this strategy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hardly "so advanced"; this is quite a common feature. Your professor is behind the times! :-) SQLite is one of the simplest databases, yet see section 11 on [this page](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#autoindex).

> Since the cost of constructing the automatic index is O(NlogN) (where
>   N is the number of entries in the table) and the cost of doing a full
>   table scan is only O(N), an automatic index will only be created if
>   SQLite expects that the lookup will be run more than logN times during
>   the course of the SQL statement

Answer (score 5):

Try to improve your google foo, here are some [results](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=dynamic%20temporary%20index%20various%20database%20engines&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=NlO&channel=fs&source=hp&q=%22temporary%20index%22%20%22query%20optimizer%22&pbx=1&oq=%22temporary%20index%22%20%22query%20optimizer%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=38389l40957l2l41213l9l8l0l0l0l3l322l2089l0.1.5.2l8l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=ee869b7db81e9425&biw=1177&bih=721)

Here are some terms:

- it is a query planner/optimizer's job to understand when it is best to use an index, which means it should understand when it is can be better to even build one temporary; see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e14261/query.htm)
- try to check also not only for "temporary indexes", but also for "hash tables" (well, depending on your definition of temporary index); see some details [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzajq/perf24.htm)

Answer (score 3):

This kind of behaviour is pretty much what you get with spooling. SQL Server can push data onto a spool, and then pull it back off again elsewhere in the query plan, taking advantage of the order that it's in.